# DataTables buttons not centered on narrow screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I have a DataTable styled with Twitter Bootstrap 3 and using some Buttons. This is the code where it gets initialized:

```
bookingsTable = $('#bookings-table').DataTable({
  language: {
    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Italian.json"
  },
  dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-4 text-center'B><'col-sm-4'f>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
  buttons: [
    {
      extend: 'excel',
      className: "btn-sm",
      text: 'Esporta',
      exportOptions: {
        columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ]
      }
    },
    {
      extend: 'colvis',
      className: "btn-sm",
      text: 'Colonne'
    },
    'refresh'
  ],
  scrollY:        500,
  scrollX:        true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  paging:         true,
  fixedColumns:   true,
  select: true 
});
```

As you can see, the buttons are centered between the `dataTables_length` and the `dataTables_filter` wrappers, which wrap the number of rows currently shown and the input search respectively.

All works as expected as long as the width is greater than 768px. When going below, the three `col-sm-4` columns correctly go on their own row each, however, while the `dataTables_length` and the `dataTables_filter` are centered, the wrapper for the buttons is left-aligned, which does not make much sense, since it has the `text-center` class which should keep it center-aligned.

Normal table:
[image: Normal table]

Shrinked table:

[image]

I think I am missing something here, however I am not able to find out the problem.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/phgw8kbx/6/) is a JSFiddle example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated: fixed the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/phgw8kbx/11/ 
the div 'dt-buttons btn-group' is using 100% width which should be auto, or you need to make the elements inline-block to be center aligned. 
just add this css somewhere and should work fine.

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.refresh = {
    text: 'Aggiorna',
    className: 'btn-sm',
    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
    }
  };

  bookingsTable = $('#bookings-table').DataTable({
    language: {
      "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Italian.json"
    },
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-4 text-center'B><'col-sm-4'f>>" +
      "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
      "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: 'excel',
        className: "btn-sm",
        text: 'Esporta',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ]
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'colvis',
        className: "btn-sm",
        text: 'Colonne'
      },
      'refresh'
    ],
    scrollY:        500,
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         true,
    fixedColumns:   true,
    select: true 
  });
});
```

```css
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!--    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico"> //TODO: set custom favicon-->

    <title>Gestione avanzata</title>

    <!-- Font Awesome v4.7.0 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <!-- Twitter Bootstrap v3.3.7 core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <!-- Bootstrap DataTables CSS v1.10.16 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <!-- DataTables Bootstrap Buttons CSS v1.5.1 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bookings_manager.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2 class="text-center">Storico prenotazioni</h2>

        <!-- Vehicles' table -->
        <div class="">
          <table id="bookings-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>ID prenotazione</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Veicolo</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Impiegato</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Centro</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Data</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Partenza da</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Ora di partenza</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Tragitto intermedio</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Ritorno a</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Ora di ritorno</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Servizio</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Motivazione</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Stato</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Storia</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Opzioni</strong></td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Modal to show the history of a booking -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="booking-history-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="booking-history-modal-label">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Chiudi"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="booking-history-modal-label">Storico prenotazione</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <table id="booking-history-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <td><strong>Impiegato</strong></td>
                  <td><strong>Azione</strong></td>
                  <td><strong>Motivazione</strong></td>
                  <td><strong>Data e ora</strong></td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Modal to permanently delete a booking -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="booking-delete-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="booking-delete-modal-label">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Chiudi"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="booking-delete-modal-label">Elimina prenotazione</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Sei sicuro di voler eliminare in maniera definitiva questa prenotazione?
            Essa verrà eliminata dal database, e non sarà più possibile recuperarla. Verrà eliminata anche dallo storico delle prenotazioni.
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm-delete-booking-button">
              <span class="fa fa-trash fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              Elimina
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal to give information about the last action (error/success) -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="action-info-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="action-info-modal-label">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" id="closeIcon" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Chiudi"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="action-info-modal-label"></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="refresh-page-button">
              <span class="fa fa-refresh fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              Aggiorna la pagina
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="report-error-button">
              <span class="fa fa-bug fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              Segnala errore
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DataTables JSzip v2.5.0 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Datatables Core JS v1.10.16 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap DataTables Core JS v1.10.16 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DataTables Buttons JS v1.5.1 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DataTables Bootstrap Buttons JS v1.5.1 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DataTables HTML5 Buttons JS v1.5.1 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DataTables Column Visbility Buttons JS v1.5.1 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Datatables fixedColumns JS v3.2.4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.4/css/fixedColumns.bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.4/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
div.dt-buttons {
    width: auto !important;
  }
```

Comment: I am not sure I have understood. I do not want the col-sm-4 to be left aligned, in fact that is the problem. I want it to be centered while in the smaller view. Even adding col-xs-12 to the buttons' wrapper does not help.

Comment: could you please provide a link where I can check it out?

Comment: I have updated my question with a link to a jsfiddle example.

Comment: I have updated my answer and it should work for you now.